# How to add a new many relationship to parent model?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework, ember-data

*Disclaimer: I tried to make a jsfiddle of this, but without a public source for the RESTAdapter, I couldn't really make it work.*

I have a model with a hasMany array of child models. I need to add a new model to this child array and save to the server:

```
App.FooModel = DS.Model.extend({
  'name': DS.attr('string'),
  'bars': DS.hasMany('App.BarModel')
});

App.BarModel = DS.Model.extend({
  'name': DS.attr('string'),
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    var foo    = App.FooModel.find(101); // -- currently has bars[201, 202, 203]
    var newBar = loadFixture( App.BarModel, 204 );

    var self = this;
    setTimeout( function() { // -- just to be sure our models are loaded before we try this
      // foo.currentState: saved
      foo.get('bars').addObject(newBar);
      // foo.currentState: saved

      foo.store.commit(); // -- nothing happens
    }, 1000);
  }
});

App = Ember.Application.create({
  store: DS.Store.create({
    revision: 11
  })
});
```

But nothing happens. My parent model doesn't get marked as dirty, so the store never attempts a commit. Is there a different way I should be adding this relationship to the parent? Is this a bug?

**Current Workaround:**

```
foo.get('bars').addObject(newBar);

var save = foo.get('name');    
foo.set('name', (save + '!'));
foo.set('name', save); // -- this marks our record as dirty, so a save will actually happen

foo.store.commit();
```

**Edit 1:** I'm aware that ember-data will only serialize this data if it was embedded to begin with (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145803/84762), but I have overridden my serializer to handle this. The issue I'm having is that the store never even attempts to save this change so we never even get to the serializer.

**Edit 2:** I suspect this *might* have something to do with [this bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2211), but at the same that would mean this wouldn't work for anyone and I have a hard time believing no one else has run into this, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're Modeling a one to many relationship yet you didn't include the `belongsTo` option on `App.BarModel`. Check this link out:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-many

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

Comment: Adding a `belongsTo` on the child didn't work, but `hasMany` on the child, did. Seems odd that they didn't both work; maybe I was doing something wrong with the `belongsTo`. In any case, thank you -- adding the relationship to the child seems to be what did the trick. I seem to remember somewhere that having a hasMany/null relationship/inverse was supported now? If not, are there plans for it? In my particular case, the child `bar` objects are used *everywhere* in the app, and I really don't want to have 25 different relationships added to the child object in order to make the parent save.

Comment: There is an inverse-null branch on Github. Perhaps they're working towards that? https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/inverse-null

Comment: I also left a comment about the linked SO question in the OP. If you could check it out, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, you did not use the `embedded` feature of relationship but overrided your serializer to handle the serialization of `bars` objects into `foo` object.

I think your bug probably came from here : if your relation is not embedded there is no reason to mark the `foo` object dirty as when you add an object to his `bars` association what should change is usually a key `foo_id` of the `bar` object you added, then there is no changes of the `foo` object to send to the API.