# Save foreign key to other Model with hasMany relation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having the following problem.

In my app I have a screen to make a new `Site`. But when I save the new site via an `action` on the controller, the `languages`-property isn't sent with the `POST`-request to the server.

The template for adding a new Site is this:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="languages">Languages</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="controllers.languages" selectionBinding="languages" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.description" multiple="true"}}
            </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <button {{ action "createSite" }} class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

I defined my `Store` like this:

```js
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision : 12,
    adapter : DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        namespace : 'rest'
    })
});
```

This is my controller:

```js
App.SitesNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['languages'],
    name: null,
    languages: null,
    createSite : function() {
        var self = this;
        var name = this.get('name');
        var languages = this.get('languages');
        // Create the new Site model
        var s = App.Site.createRecord({
            name : name
        });
        $.each(languages,function(i,lang) {
            s.get('languages').addObject(lang);
        });

        this.get('store').commit();
    }
});
```

This is the `Site`-model

```js
App.Site = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    languages : DS.hasMany('App.Language')
});
```

`Language`-model:

```js
App.Language = DS.Model.extend({
    description : DS.attr('string')
});
```

The `POST`-request data sent to my server is this:

```js
{
  "site":{"name":"test"}
}
```

So I miss the `language`-property. Actually I expect a `language_ids` property with an array of id's.

When I edit my `RESTAdapter`-configuration like this:

```js
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Site', {
    languages: { embedded: 'always' }
});
```

Now the `POST`-request data is:

```js
{
  "site": {
    "name":"test",
    "languages":[{
      "id":2,"description":"English"
    },{
      "id":3,"description":"Deutsch"
    }]
  }
}
```

The languages are know embedded in the request-data. This is no problem, at the backend I get the `id` before I save it. But know it expects the `language`-data to be embedded in the GET-responses also.

What is the way to send just the `id`'s in the POST-data? I want it to be something like this:

```js
{
  "site": {
    "name":"test",
    "languages":[2,3]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is largely derived from [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145803/2166890).

```js
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision : 12,
    adapter : DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        namespace : 'rest',
        serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
            addHasMany: function (hash, record, key, relationship) {
                var type = record.constructor,
                    name = relationship.key,
                    serializedHasMany = [], 
                    manyArray, embeddedType;

                embeddedType = this.embeddedType(type, name);
                if (embeddedType !== 'always') { return; }

                manyArray = record.get(name);

                manyArray.forEach(function (record) {
                    serializedHasMany.push(record.get('id'));
                }, this);

                hash[this.singularize(key) + '_ids'] = serializedHasMany;
            }

        })

    })
});
```

For reference, you might review the `JSONSerializer`, which the `RESTSerializer` mostly inherits from. The code for what `addHasMany` does can be found [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/7e968d4b365cbec242cb820ec8cae9e46abdddf7/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L119-155).

Note that, for the above snippet, the only lines that really differ are the last several. Rather than serializing embedded records, ids are pushed to the hash under the singularized key (I would have used `RESTSerializer#keyForHasMany` if it didn't [have its own check for embedded types](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/7e968d4b365cbec242cb820ec8cae9e46abdddf7/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L21-23).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I read the source-code and I totally get it. It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the killer answer. I've omitted the embeddedType !== 'always' check so I can get both sideloading and multiple hasMany id upload

Comment: PS. the code has a little bug, it's not able to correctly map camelcase properties to REST convention (eg. childNodes becomes childNode_ids instead of child_node_ids). A workaround is to modify the following at the end of the serializer object: key = this.keyForAttributeName(type, name); hash[this.singularize(key) + '_ids'] = serializedHasMany;