# How to add in hasMany relationship with the Ember Data local storage adapter/serializer?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using the Ember local storage adapter for an app that has two models: Organizations and Members. The relationship is that Organizations "hasMany" Members, and Members "belongsTo" Organizations, as follows:

```
App.Org = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  members: DS.hasMany('App.Member')
});

App.Member = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  org: DS.belongsTo('App.Org')
});
```

In the [jsbin of the app](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/252/edit), you can add members and the organizations to the local storage, which works perfectly (meaning that when I add a new organization, its selected members are added in the "members" hasMany relationship).

In addition to adding the new organization information, I would like to serialize the newly created organization record to be sent over to a server via AJAX (no I not want to use the RESTAdapter).

However, the "members" hasMany relationship is completely missing from the serialization, so this is the serialization that I'm getting (you can [see for yourself if you add some members and then open up the console](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/252)):

```
{ 
    name: "Organization name",
    description: "description of the org"
}
```

and this is the serialization that I would like:

```
{ 
    name: "Organization name",
    description: "description of the org",
    members: ["id_of_member_1", "id_of_member_2", "id_of_member_3"]
}
```

This is how I am doing the serialization:

```
App.OrganizationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    createOrg: function(){
        var neworg = App.Org.createRecord({
          name: this.get('newname'),
          description: this.get('newdescription')
        });
        neworg.get('members').pushObjects(this.get('newmembers'));
        neworg.save();

        var serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.create({});
        console.log(serializer.serialize(neworg));
    }
    ...
```

If serialization is not the way to go, another way might be making "members" a string array attribute, but so far this path has failed me.

In addition to suggestions, please provide a working jsbin based on the [current jsbin of the app](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/252/edit). Because I've [tried](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/866) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145803/733034) that don't work.

Keep in mind this app is set up with an Ember Data local storage adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`.  `org-serializer.js` would look like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    members: { serialize: 'ids' }
  }
});
```

See the documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html#toc_using-embedded-records).