# What is the correct way to persist child model with Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Problem

I'm teaching myself Ember and having problems persisting my child models. Here's a JSBin that demonstrates the problem:

http://jsbin.com/OnUXEti/2/edit?html,js,output

If you play with it, you will be able to create Posts and Comments, but only the Posts are still available after a page reload. (I'm using ember-data and the localStorage adapter)

---

There are two model types, `Post` and `Comment`

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Each Post has an array of Comments.
I intend there to be the following URLs:

- `/posts` will list all the Posts
- `/posts/1` will display the Post with id 1
- `/posts/1/comments` will display the Comments for Post 1

Routes are defined like so:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", { path: "/posts" });
  this.resource("post", { path: "/posts/:post_id" }, function() {
    this.resource("comments", { path: "/comments" });
  });
});
```

I am able to write Post models to the store without problem. What I cannot do is save the Comment models. If you play with my JSBin example above you will see that you can create comments but they are not persisted when reloading the page.

I attempt to save Comments in the CommentsController:

```
App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: "post",
    post: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.post"),
    newMessage: '',
    actions: {
        create: function() {
            var message = this.get('newMessage');

            var comment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {
                message : message
            });

            this.set('newMessage', '');

            var post = this.get('post');
            var comments = post.get('comments');
            comments.pushObject(comment);
            comment.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that I am getting a handle on the parent Post by using the `needs` property. Taken from the [documentation about dependencies between controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

This all feels wrong as it should be a common situation so I suspect I've designed my models or routes in a non-standard way.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I see the problem, i am trying out your fiddle... it seems your model is getting updated but your post model seems not get reflected... which is mapped to your comment objects...

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138219/ember-data-saving-a-relationship/15145803#15145803

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you need to save the `post` after adding the `comment` to its `comments` collection.  It looks like the `LSAdapter` stores the array of comment ids directly in the `post` record.

Here's a modified JSBin : http://jsbin.com/OnUXEti/8/edit

Note: I also changed this :

`post: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.post")`

to this:

`post: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.post.model")`

In order to save the `post` you want to be dealing with the actual model, not the controller.

I also had to update Ember Data and the LSAdapter to get things to work, and I changed the `hasMany` relationship on `comments` to be `async`.

```
comments: DS.hasMany('comment',{async:true})
```

[UPDATE] : I originally posted the wrong JSBin.  The correct one is : http://jsbin.com/OnUXEti/8/edit

Comment: +1 : wow,, i did make changes to the post attribute, but did not change the relationship.... awesome...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! You are a scholar and a saint! Thanks to you I have realised that I had 2 problems: 1) I was not saving the 'post' model. 2) I needed to use ember-data-latest.js.  I have created another JSBin that just does the minimum changes needed to get it to work. Note that I did not need to update LSAdapter nor did I set the 'async' option on my post model. http://jsbin.com/OnUXEti/17/edit?html,js,output  If I could give you more points I would, I was about to give up on ember just as I was starting to love it :) Thanks again, Matt.

Comment: Ahh, I needed the async option otherwise sometimes I would get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined". Thanks again!

Comment: For me I needed async and I had not defined the serializer for my adapter: App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.LSSerializer.extend();