# LocalStorage Data Adapter and hasMany Relationship in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application im using [LSA](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) and im need to use relation in my model for example i have post and comment models like this :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
 title:DS.attr('string'),
 comments:DS.hasMany('comments')
});

App.Comments=DS.Model.extend({
 content:DS.attr('string'),
 post:DS.belongsTo('post')
});
```

i want to know ho to create a child relationship between post and comments and how to update commnets of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also been struggling to do this properly. See [What is the correct way to persist child model with Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792696/what-is-the-correct-way-to-persist-child-model-with-ember-js) and 
[Ember children defined by a hasMany relationship suddenly change to embedded model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878836/ember-children-defined-by-a-hasmany-relationship-suddenly-change-to-embedded-mod)

I ended up writing my own fix for the problems I found. See the pull request here: https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/pull/26